# How to use POP3 in PHP 5.6 without ugly php_imap?

Tags: php, email, email-attachments, pop3, php-5.6

I use default `php_imap` module at the moment for downloading mails from my POP3 mailbox/server in php application. It works. However, it has more disadvantages (non-oop API, incomplete pop3 support) than actual functions. Recently it stopped working and is not giving me file names, sometimes it can't event download files (not because of network issues).

I could not find other cases to use POP3 in PHP. I believe there must be solution for my simple requirements:

- Connect/login POP3 mailbox
- List thousands of inbox messages
- Get headers, filenames and filesizes without downloading attachments
- Download attachments i need (from new mails only for example), to memory

I have PHP 5.6 on Linux server. I tried to run:

```
pecl install pecl_pop3
```

But it's too outdated (last release in 2005) and could not be compiled.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That about this? http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mail.read.html or this https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: @Axalix Thanks. why didn't you post this as an answer?

Comment: No problem. There are just 2 links for the reference.